# Shape, Sprite, MovieClip and other display objects: when to use?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, optimization, displayobject

there's a large ammount of display objects in `flash.display` package. It's not clear for me in what situation I should use `Shape`, `Sprite` or `MovieClip`. What is the pro and contras in using each of them?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [Shape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html) is the simplest display object you can add on stage. It is
  the most limited one: you can't add childen to it (does not extend DisplayObjectContainer), does not have interactivity (does not extend InteractiveObject), does not have a timeline
- [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) extends DisplayObjectContainer and InteractiveObject, therefore it's interactive and you can add children to it. It's the most useful display class in my opinion, as long as you don't need a timeline.
- [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.htmlhttp://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) extends Sprite, so all of the above are true and you also get methods/properties associated with timeline control, but note that it's a **dynamic** class, so you can do some hacky thing on the fly, but you'll lose speed.

In short, stick to Sprite in most cases, unless you need to integrate with MovieClips from Flash Authoring. Shape is handy to quickly draw into and it's 'lighter' than Sprite, but not very flexible since you can't nest other elements to it.

Answer (score 3):

You should always use the lightest component depending on what you need:

- `Shape` is the one with the least possibilities. Use it when you only want a `DisplayObject` with `graphics`, and no mouse interaction.
- `Sprite` is the parent class of quite everything you need. Since it is a `DisplayObjectContainer`, you can use it as a basic container for other components. You can also catch mouse events on this one.
- `MovieClip` is a `Sprite` with the ability to use frames. Only use it for frame-by-frame animation (Flash style).