# AS3: MouseEvent not working?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I click on it nothing is being outputted. Is there a reason why the MouseEvent is not being applied to the rectangle. Where am I going wrong?

My Code:

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

var rectangle001:Shape = new Shape;

rectangle001.graphics.beginFill(0x00D783);
rectangle001.graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
rectangle001.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rectangle001Click);
function rectangle001Click (event:MouseEvent){
trace("Hello World!");
}
addChild(rectangle001);
```

All answers appreciated.

Comment: Try MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, and also change `Shape` to `Sprite`

Comment: Thanks, changing to Sprite fixed it. Any idea why shapes can't have MouseEvents?

Answer (score 2):

You should use *Sprite* instead of *Shape* if you want mouse interactivity.

Quoting from an answer on **[this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192923/shape-sprite-movieclip-and-other-display-objects-when-to-use)**:

> - Shape is the one with the least possibilities. Use it when you only want a DisplayObject with graphics, and no mouse interaction.
> - Sprite is the parent class of quite everything you need. Since it is a DisplayObjectContainer, you can use it as a basic container for other components. You can also catch mouse events on this one.
> - MovieClip is a Sprite with the ability to use frames. Only use it for frame-by-frame animation (Flash style).